# *.aclpolicy file not works - Auth using Active Directory

Tags: authentication, rundeck

Summarizing my environment:

- Running Rundeck (3.3.11) at Kuberenetes Cluster
- Dedicated Database MariaDB connected via JDBC Connector.
- Configured Active Directory via JAAS using the variables `RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_ *` and auth working, I can logon using my AD user.
- Configured ACL Policy template using K8s Secret like in this [Zoo sample](https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo/blob/master/kubernetes/rundeckpro-deployment.yaml):

```
         volumeMounts:
            - name: aclpolicy
              mountPath: /home/rundeck/etc/rundeck-adm.aclpolicy
              subPath: rundeck-adm.aclpolicy
      volumes:
        - name: aclpolicy
          secret:
            secretName: rundeck-adm-policy
            items:
            - key: rundeck-admin-role.yaml
              path: rundeck-adm.aclpolicy
```

Variables exported to Rundeck Pod:

```
RUNDECK_JAAS_MODULES_0=JettyCombinedLdapLoginModule
RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_USERBASEDN=OU=Users,OU=MYBRAND,DC=corp,DC=MYDOMAIN
RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_ROLEBASEDN=OU=RundeckRoles,OU=Users,OU=MYBRAND,DC=corp,DC=MYDOMAIN
RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_FLAG=sufficient
RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_BINDDN=myrundeckuser@mybrand.mydomain
RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_BINDPASSWORD=foo
```

In my MS Active Directory the structure is:

```
-mybrand.mydomain
 - MYBRAND
   - Users
     - RundeckRoles
       - rundeck-adm (group with my user associated)
```

After I login returns this screen:
[image]

**EDIT1**:
My `rundeck-admin-role.yaml`:

```
description: Admin project level access control. Applies to resources within a specific project.
context:
  project: '.*' # all projects
for:
  resource:
    - equals:
        kind: job
      allow: [create] # allow create jobs
    - equals:
        kind: node
      allow: [read,create,update,refresh] # allow refresh node sources
    - equals:
        kind: event
      allow: [read,create] # allow read/create events
  adhoc:
    - allow: [read,run,runAs,kill,killAs] # allow running/killing adhoc jobs
  job:
    - allow: [create,read,update,delete,run,runAs,kill,killAs] # allow create/read/write/delete/run/kill of all jobs
  node:
    - allow: [read,run] # allow read/run for nodes
by:
  group: rundeck-adm

---

description: Admin Application level access control, applies to creating/deleting projects, admin of user profiles, viewing projects and reading system information.
context:
  application: 'rundeck'
for:
  resource:
    - equals:
        kind: project
      allow: [create] # allow create of projects
    - equals:
        kind: system
      allow: [read,enable_executions,disable_executions,admin] # allow read of system info, enable/disable all executions
    - equals:
        kind: system_acl
      allow: [read,create,update,delete,admin] # allow modifying system ACL files
    - equals:
        kind: user
      allow: [admin] # allow modify user profiles
  project:
    - match:
        name: '.*'
      allow: [read,import,export,configure,delete,admin] # allow full access of all projects or use 'admin'
  project_acl:
    - match:
        name: '.*'
      allow: [read,create,update,delete,admin] # allow modifying project-specific ACL files
  storage:
    - allow: [read,create,update,delete] # allow access for /ssh-key/* storage content

by:
  group: rundeck-adm
```

Someone can help me to find my mistake?

Comment: Where is you actual admin-role.aclpolicy? probably just a yaml syntax error in the acl policy itself.

Comment: @Maayana, I update my post and added my rundeck-admin-role.yaml

Comment: In the screenshot seems that the user isn't part of rundeck-adm roles (without roles), make sure to configure AD/Rundeck integration well. Take a look at this: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/docker.html#user-authentication and this: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/docker.html#user-authentication (a good approach to test your AD conf is using a test/local war rundeck instance against your AD server).

Comment: @MegaDrive68k So I follow this docs that you refer to me, but I'm trying to solve why my user don't get the policy based in the group at my active directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys I found the trouble!

It was missing to add some variables `RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_ROLEMEMBERATTRIBUTE` and `RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_ROLEOBJECTCLASS`, by *default* if you don't declare that, Rundeck assume another values.
After I apply this *vars* and re-deploy my Rundeck Pod back works my access using my AD Account.

To help the community I'm making available the list of vars that I used in my deployment:

```
"JVM_MAX_RAM_PERCENTAGE"
"RUNDECK_DATABASE_URL"
"RUNDECK_DATABASE_DRIVER"
"RUNDECK_DATABASE_USERNAME"
"RUNDECK_DATABASE_PASSWORD"
"RUNDECK_LOGGING_AUDIT_ENABLED"
"RUNDECK_JAAS_MODULES_0"
"RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_FLAG"
"RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_PROVIDERURL"
"RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_BINDDN"
"RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_BINDPASSWORD"
"RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_USERBASEDN"
"RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_ROLEBASEDN"
"RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL"
"RUNDECK_SERVER_FORWARDED"
"RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_USERRDNATTRIBUTE"
"RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_USERIDATTRIBUTE"
"RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_ROLEMEMBERATTRIBUTE"
```

The **JAAS** plugin that I use was: `JettyCombinedLdapLoginModule`